# Keep selection after closing popup

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I need to keep the selection of the column after closing the popup.
I've used this solution (which was posted in this link :
[Keep selection when refreshing datagrid in ActionScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978905/keep-selection-when-refreshing-datagrid-in-actionscript)) in other view and it works very good  when I stay on the same view but when I open a popup and I return, it does not work.
Can you help me please ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the query then in the same discussion page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selectedIndex in a global variable. Then after opening a popup and returning you will be able to set the selectedIndex.

Ex.:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.selectedIndexOfDataGrid = dataGrid.selectedIndex;
... opening pupup ... etc...
dataGrid.selectedIndex = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.selectedIndexOfDataGrid;
```

Where selectedIndexOfDataGrid is a public variable in your main .mxml file.

```
public var selectedIndexOfDataGrid:Number;
```

Comment: Hi Ivan. Thank you very much. I'll use your solution And come back to tell What happened with it.